# What's the subtle difference between certificate and credential?

Tags: synonyms

What's the subtle difference between **certificate** and **credential**?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about why an Android phone does what it does.

Comment: Ask Android why not.

Comment: @Drew: "Certificate of employment" is an Android matter? "

Comment: @Amadan: The question was edited after my comment. It was *My Android phone shows me a menu item as "Credential Storage", why does it not use "Certificate Storage"?*  Why Android uses this and not that is OT.

Comment: As the question stands now, it should be closed for a different reason: it is answered by standard reference material, e.g., a dictionary.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it makes the assumption that words that are used with different senses in some contexts cannot have overlapping ones in other contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the broadest sense, a certificate is a certain type of credential, but may be one among many. For example, in Illinois, a barber has to have a state license, which is a credential. The barber may also have a certificate from a barber college, another type of credential, and, if he has chosen to locate his barber shop in a municipality, the barber may have a license to do business in that municipality, and a Tax certificate, if he is selling hair tonic and other supplies upon which he must charge retailers tax.

Comment: This just sounds like splitting hairs.

Comment: Pehaps, but many words exist because of the need to "split hairs".

Comment: Positively barberous.